AutoCAD - Change Layer if Specific parameters are met
First time poster, hoping I could get some help because this is baffling me.
I have a layout with a boundary. After filling the boundary and cutting everything I sit with multiple closed polylines within the boundary.


As you can see from the images all the polylines are the same size and have a certain gap between them. Where the circle is, is basically a new set, so it does not form part of the above section.
I have a Layer for each number of closed polylines in a row. 1,2,3...etc up until 8. So 8 is max.
Now to the Question.....
I need to write something that will be able to check and count the polylines and assign the correct layer to those closed polylines.
I should be able to write the code, but to honest I do not know how to go about this.
I have a Userform that currently does other functions, but it focusses mostly on quantitys and lengths. I would like to build on this so I'm looking for something that can be done in VBA.
PS. Everything is automated up until this point and I would like to keep it automated.
EDIT: I do not know where to start...(I'm Approaching it differently)
I adding a line that intersects 8 sets of plines when I populate the boundary, all I have to do now is check each line, count how many are bain intersected, then apply layer to each pline.
Pink Intersect Lines
This code below is what I'm busy with and trying to get what I want. The Code is not working in current form, it is just a representation of what I'm trying to do, Still figuring it out
    Sub addLayers()

Dim intLine As AcadLine
Dim StringPLine As AcadLine
Dim CountString As Long
Dim acSelSet As AcadSelectionSet
Dim selObject As AcadEntity

'///Looping thru each line in drawing
For Each intLine In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
Set acSelSet = CreateSelectionSet("sset", ThisDrawing)

'///Looping thru all polylines and checking if it intersects with Line
For Each StringPLine In ThisDrawing.ModelSpace
If intLine.IntersectWith(StringPLine, acExtendNone) = True Then

'///Add to selection set
acSelSet.AddItems StringPLine
End If
Next

'///Looping thru each selected entity
For Each selObject In acSelSet
'Add layer name to entity
selObject.Layer = "0_" & acSelSet.count & "Strings"
Next

acSelSet.Delete
Next
End Sub

WeTransfer link for Example.dwg File

It seems the color-coding (and layer assignment?) is based on the height of segments. But, in the lower part of Full Site view there is a yellow section under light-green section which It's not clear a bug in the current code or is by design. Anyway, it is better to assign layers to objects (plines) where they are created. Can you attach the code?

Hi @ShahramAlemzadeh
All of objects were counted and assigned layers manually.  I'm looking to create something that would automate this step.
Each pline is 30m long, Gap between them are 0,4m. There can be 1 to 8 plines in a row.

@ShahramAlemzadeh
To get polylines inside the Boundary - I create a pattern and cover the boundary, Then using Maptrim and Quick Select I remove all plines outside boundary and remove open plines.

I found when I go to write code I start by thinking about what the process is when I do it manually.  I'll break it into a numbered list.  I will then look at my list and see if anything repeats itself and if they do flag that as called procedure or function.  I then go look at my list and then check if I know how to approach each of the steps.  If I do not, I flag it for research.  If I spend too much time researching how to do it, I ask here.  I then start coding the easy stuff to get the ball rolling.

Some questions do stand out.  You say you want to have it move stuff to a layer automatically.  How are you determining what layer stuff belongs to?

so the layer name would be "0_1 String" if there is only one pline (Yellow), If there is 2 plines (Orange) the layer would be "0_2 String" ....etc. Ive addded some code to my question

@ForwardEd Thanks for the above method of how you do things, this is certainly something I will adopt.

Is the 1 because the pline is yellow or 1 because because the number of yellow plines is 1?  If its a count of the number of lines of a certain colour type I'd make a counter for each expected colour type and then when looping through I would use a CASE statement and the corresponding CASE action for a particular colour would be to add one to its specific colour counter.

If you are working with the basic 256 colours and greys, you could make an array for the count and use the colour number as the index number for the array.

As an aside, AutoCAD dropped official support for VBA in AutoCAD a couple of versions back.  You can still use it, but no guarantee all commands and features will be supported.
